# AngularJS $watch doesn't wait for trigger to happen, executes the $scope inside the callback function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have the below code

Fiddler [Link](http://jsfiddle.net/7wr6ow57/)

**Html:**

```
 <div ng-app ng-controller="ParentCtrl" ng-init="cities='North America'">
        <div ng-controller="ChildCtrl as vm">
           {{$parent.cities}}
           <div>
             <button ng-click="check()">Check the value</button>
           </div>
        </div>
 </div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
 function ParentCtrl($scope, $rootScope) {        
        $rootScope.$watch('changecity', function() {       
          $scope.cities = "South America";
          console.log("changed the city");                            
        });

        $scope.cities = "North America";
    }

    function ChildCtrl($scope, $rootScope) {                              
        $scope.check = function(){
            console.log("$parent value:"+$scope.$parent.cities + "\n$scope value:"+$scope.cities)        
        };
    }
```

I have `ng-init = "cities='North America'"` and also `$scope.cities = "North America";` in `ParentCtrl`.

But the view at the output is updated as **South America** which is strange. Can somebody explain the whole funda of execution happening in the above code chunk.

1. Is `$watch` callback executed initially?
2. What will be the precedence of scope overriding, ie: Scope inside the watch callback overrides the values previously set?

Comment: Don't use `ng-init` for that purpose. Declare variables in controller

Answer (score 2):

`$watch` starts watching when the variable is `undefined`. $watch will be triggered at initialization as it views `undefined` as a new state change in the scope-variable. Besides that the setting of the scope-variable `$scope.cities = 'North America'` is seen as a change in the variable. This change triggers the `$watch`, which in turn changes `$scope.cities='South America'`.

To fix this just check if the old value is not `undefined`:

```
$rootScope.$watch('changecity', function(newvalue, oldvalue) {       
      // This will only change the cities if the original value was falsy
      if(oldvalue) {
         $scope.cities = "South America";
         console.log("changed the city");                            
      }
    });
```

For reference see: http://jsfiddle.net/7wr6ow57/4/

Comment: ok well now i have removed all the initial assignment that sets the scope to **North America**. Follow this updated fiddler http://jsfiddle.net/7wr6ow57/2/ . So now what triggers the `$watch` to set it to **south america**? i still can see the same output.

Comment: $watch also sees `undefined` as a new state at initialization. So it will always trigger in this case. I'll update my answer ;)

Comment: If you have solved your question using a different solution, and don't want to accept my answer, you should create answer to your own question and accept that. Otherwise, it will not be clear to people what the solution is... This question would then just remain open for no good reason as it has been solved. ;)

Comment: Yes sure. But mine is not a definite answer although.. but tries to give the perspective of how `$watch` actually works. Thanks to your soln which helped me to figure out possible explanation but not the exact solution. Anyways i will post the code i tried. May be it helps someone out there